# Why is os.listdir() causing excessive memory usage?

Tags: python, memory-leaks

I'm writing a script to gather stats from a large amount of data (~1TB) stored on an external drive. I noticed I was just about out of memory, but the memory allocated by python.exe was only around 11MB. When I ejected the drive, around 4GB of memory was instantly freed.

In trying to track down the issue, I'm able to reproduce the problem running the following code on Windows 7, Windows 8 and OSX 10.9 using USB2 on Windows 7 and USB3 on Windows 8 and OSX, and using Python 2.7.6 and 2.7.8:

```
    # listFile.txt is a list of all folders with relevant data, about 14,000 lines
    import os
    with open('listFile.txt', 'r') as listFile:
        for line in listFile.readlines():
            foo = len(os.listdir(line[:-1])) # line[:-2] for Mac testing
```

Since there are thousands of folders and millions of files, this takes a long time to execute. As it runs, memory usage as reported by Task Manager/Activity Monitor steadily climbs at around 1GB every 15 minutes. The memory usage reported for python.exe remains steady. This memory is not freed when the code finishes executing, only when the drive is ejected or unplugged.  Any ideas why this is happening? What is being written to memory, and why is the usage not reported in any process?

EDIT
It looks like tobias_k is right. I was able to reproduce the memory usage using ls -l in bash.

Comment: You should really use `for line in listFile` as `.readlines()` reads the whole file into memory. `os.listdir(line.rstrip())` will remove whitespace from the end without having to slice so exact.

Comment: Other than that, `os.listdir()` is an almost pure OS call, using `opendir()` / `readdir()` / `closedir()` on Mac, and their Win32 equivalents on Windows.

Comment: Can you identify which process is actually spiking in memory?

Comment: Last but not least, can you reproduce the same memory pattern using, say, Perl or pure command-line utilities (`ls`, `xargs`, `wc -l` come to mind).

Comment: I cannot find a process that is using all the memory. It doesn't appear to be reported anywhere. Process Explorer doesn't show anything out of the ordinary. I'll try reproducing the problem with a bash script.